# I cannot get the base url of my NextJS application in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I need to configure the baseUrl for axios in NextJS for server side rendering, so in nodejs.
Currentl I am using

```
  axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_BASE_URL + "/api";
```

but the value is always undefined in nodejs and browser

any idea how to setup properly?